# Select rows based on user input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to implement a way for a spreadsheet to get data from specific rows of another spreadsheet based on a user input.  so if the user inputs 1-5 it will pull the sum of A1:A5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would INDEX to set the upper and lower bounds:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,C1):INDEX(A:A,C2))
```

Where C1 is the lower number, like `1` and C2 is the upper number, like `5`

Comment: Thank you very much that was actually much easier than I imagined it.